# Delete a line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I got a javascript function that add lines in a read-only textarea, example:
If I press a button to launch my function, my textarea contains:

```
Line abcdef
```

And if I click again, I get:

```
Line abcdef
Line ghijkl
```

The function is:

```
function addLine() {
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value +=
        'Line ' + document.getElementById('textinput').value + '\r\n';
}
```

But now I want to be able to delete the latest added line, in case the user make a mistake and wants to correct it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this

Comment: There's definitely a way, yes; but given you're showing a list of entries, why not use a simple list associated with hidden, or read-only inputs?

Comment: You should take a look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JMjag/

Comment: I don't think a textarea is the right element to use for this.

Comment: What should I use then ?

Comment: If it's read only anyway, why not put just `<span>` tag with each line, or `<div>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split on newlines, and remove the last one :

```
function removeLine(selector) {
    var elem = document.querySelector(selector),
        val  = elem.value.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g).filter(function(n){
                  return n.trim()
               });
    val.pop();
    elem.value = val.join('\r\n') + '\r\n';
}
// i.e. removeLine('#myTextarea');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6KcK/)

Comment: Won't the fact that he prints: line + '\r\n' cause your code to just remove the '\r\n' at the end and not the entire line?

Comment: Works, except that when you del a line and add a new one she goes next to the other not under... thanks anyway!

Comment: @adeneo +1 I didn't notice the pop before. That was what was missing, I believe you don't need the filter.

Comment: @Osmoz That's because the new line is missing at the end. I edited it.

Comment: Just add a newline at the end

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, i'd never have been able to do that myself !

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you..

```
function removeLine()
{
    var removeval = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
    removeval = removeval.trim();
    var n = removeval.split("\n");
    delete n[(n.length)-1];
    var newval = n.join('\n');
    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value = newval;
}
```